# How to add custom MeterRegisty for Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am currently exporting Actuator metrics for my Spring Boot Webflux project to DataDog with 10 seconds interval. I would like to add another exporter for one of our internal system that is not in the list of supported backends. Looking at the implementation from `DataDogMeterRegistry` I came up with the following.

```
public interface ExternalConfig extends StepRegistryConfig {

  ExternalConfig DEFAULT = k -> null;

  @Override
  default String prefix() {
    return "vwexternal";
  }
}

@Slf4j
public class ExternalMeterRegistry extends StepMeterRegistry {

  public ExternalMeterRegistry() {
    this(ExternalConfig.DEFAULT, Clock.SYSTEM);
  }

  public ExternalMeterRegistry(StepRegistryConfig config, Clock clock) {
    super(config, clock);
  }

  @Override
  protected void publish() {
    log.info("HERE");
  }

  @Override
  protected TimeUnit getBaseTimeUnit() {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
  }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    Metrics.addRegistry(new ExternalMeterRegistry());
  }
}
```

However this is not working since no logs are printed.

My question is how can I add and implement another MeterRegistry for Spring Boot Micrometer?

Comment: I believe you need to call `super.publish()` in your publish method

Comment: No that is a abstract method and can not be called directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `start` the publishing. Compare with the [`LoggingMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/logging/LoggingMeterRegistry.java#L75)

In your constructor something like:

```
start(new NamedThreadFactory("vw-metrics-publisher"))
```